# Exact need of jquery.validate.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I am working in Mvc4. Creating client side validation using jquery. I have created a view. But the validation still working without the validate.js file. May be the uses will be in another way. Can someone please explain me what and how the validate.js file will be used to implement client side validation in Mvc?
Below is my index view page.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form id="Form" method="get" action="">
<p>
    <label>
        Name</label>
    <input id="cname" name="name" type="text" required="" /></p>
<p>
    <label>
        E-Mail</label>
    <input id="cemail" type="text" name="email" required=""></p>
<p>
    <label>
        Your comment</label>
    <textarea id="ccomment" name="comment" required="Required" rows="" cols=""></textarea></p>
<p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: That's because you are using HTML5 validation (the `required` attribute), not jquery validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Validate is just an addon for jQuery you could use. So you still got to write the validation yourself, even though jQuery Validate makes a lot of things easier.

[Here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) is a documentation on the plugin you should check out, to use it for your needs.

Comment: @Amit, the jQuery Validate plugin is also built into ASP and facilitated by the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin, so maybe you should check into that first.

Comment: @Sparky,Thanks sparky for your kind reply.